# Refresh tokens in web apps locked by PIN

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I've been doing some investigation into the use of refresh tokens in web apps - specifically server side rendered web apps such as ASP.NET Core MVC or Spring MVC, but this could apply to SPAs as well...

Seems like it's considered a somewhat acceptible practice so long as:

1. There is refresh token rotation whereby; a) refresh tokens are
   automatically invalidated upon use, and b) if/when a refresh token
   that has already been invalidated is re-used, then all refresh
   tokens from the same family will be automatically invalidated.
2. Refresh tokens must have an absolute expiry that cannot be reset by
   new rotated refresh tokens (i.e beyond the absolute lifetime of the initial
   refresh token).
3. Secure storage e.g. using cookies that are `Secure`, `HttpOnly` and
   `SameSite=Strict` (or even `SameSite=Lax` seems reasonable to me if proper precautions are
   taken) to protect against XSS and CSRF respectively.

See the section about [refresh tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-12#name-refresh-tokens) in draft IETF BCP for "OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps" for more information. [This](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-single-page-applications-with-refresh-token-rotation/) Auth0 blog is also a pretty good description for how refresh token rotation works.

Anyways, with the native apps that I've been involved in, refresh tokens have been typically stored securely in the device key store (e.g. iOS keychain) and can be unlocked with a PIN (or biometric) that gets set immediately after the initial auth.

For web apps where refresh tokens can be stored in secure cookies, should there be a PIN involved somehow?.. if so, how does this work? If not (because of things like refresh token rotation etc) should refresh tokens still need to be locked by PINs in native apps?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh tokens have been used in web and mobile apps for many years. They provide a mechanism for keeping API message credentials short lived. It is not usual to involve end users in technical prompts about refresh tokens though.

Typically, if a refresh token lifetime is 4 hours, and an access token 15 minutes, you only involve the user once every 4 hours. If you are working with high worth data such as a banking app, you might reduce these times further.

**WEB APPS**

The main mitigation here is to keep tokens out of the browser via secure cookies, and protect against XSS / CSRF, as you are doing.

**MOBILE APPS**

Storing tokens in secure storage private to the app is common. Also, when your app starts it can verify that a PIN (or stronger) has been configured on the device, to provide protection against an attacker being able to see your app's data, if the device is stolen.

**STRONG AUTHENTICATION**

A PIN is most commonly used during multi-factor workflows. A modern example might be using a passkey or other user-verifiable WebAuthn device. This provides strong crypto based login, combining `something the user has` and `something the user knows`.

Another technique can involve only issuing high privilege claims in access tokens when strong authentication is used.

**SUMMARY**

The browser is not a perfect place to execute code  All you can do is follow OAuth and XSS best practices. Consider combining that with both a friendly user experience and strong authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following approach (see sequence diagram below) for using refresh tokens in web app **with a PIN**.

This approach should work for both SPAs and server side rendered web apps using 'authorization code grant' and 'authorization code grant with PKCE' respectively.

The refresh token in the Cookie is encrypted using the PIN (so that you need the PIN to unlock the refresh token) and is configured to be `HttpOnly` and `SameSite=Strict` to protect against XSS and CSRF attacks.

Keen to get this critiqued, to see if this approach is sound...

[image]